hi expert, how to modify pda field in my program
i defined a struct:
#[account]
pub struct AcctEntity {
    owner_id: Vec<u8>,
    big_brothr_acct_addr: String,
    aaa_addr: String, 
    question_nos: String,
    bump: u8,
}

after i create it . I want to modify the field 'aaa_addr', how to write the code in anchor?
use assignment is invalid....

You'll need to create a new ix with the required fields, assuming that the AccEntity account is initialized already,
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct UpdateEntity<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub acc_entity: Account<'info, AcctEntity>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}


Inside your program module, use the update instruction
    pub fn update(ctx: Context<UpdateEntity>, new_addr: String) -> Result<()> {
        let acc = &mut ctx.accounts.acc_entity;

        acc.aaa_addr = new_addr;

        Ok(())
    }


it is not work.  my created account is a pda, my code is same as you, it has no error, but  the data is also not be overwritted.  Through google, I may need to use try_borrow_mut_data first, then deserialize, modify and then serialize and save back, but I do not know this code at present, so I come to ask for help

Anchor handles serialization and deserialization for you. could you explain more about what you are trying to achieve?

I have added my code in the following answer, please help me

could you explain what you are trying to do and the hindrance you are facing in doing so. Add any errors logs you are encountering.

There were no errors during execution, but the actual changes did not take effect. My goal is to create pda(user_acct) in function create_acct, And save the user_passwd_acct's address to user_acct.passwd_addr. Then in the function change_acct_passwd_addr I overwrite the address of new_passwd_acct to user_acct.passwd_addr, but when I use the equal sign assignment, the overwrite does not take effect, the data does not change, the execution process does not have any errors, and the system returns success. by the way, in change_acct_passwd_addr, the lamports 's change is valid

Your code is correct so I don't see where the error is coming from. does question_nos update its value? also, what are you using to check whether the password was updated?

Both passwd_addr and question_nos  are invalid

OK. Thank you very much for your patient answer

I've got it.. see my answer below

I'm newbie. my code (lib.rs & test code) is below:
the program is: The last modified variable output in the test code, passwd, is unchanged and is on line 250 of the test code. (search string "250")
==========
lib.rs:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
// use anchor_lang::solana_program::keccak;
// use anchor_lang::solana_program::system_program;
// use anchor_lang::{solana_program::entrypoint::ProgramResult, system_program::{transfer, Transfer}};
// use anchor_lang::solana_program::ed25519_program;
// use anchor_lang::solana_program::sysvar;

declare_id!("BA3YWB1TPRqMcKjMRBugDqjcowNiZJb4FcPwjWfg9aCD");

#[program]
pub mod easyaccess {

    // todo : The fee transfer to payer did not materialize


    use super::*;

    /**
     * lamports: transfer amount in lamports
     * trans_fee_lamports: transaction's fee, which should be minus from entity account, and add to payer.
     * the ownerId must endsWith 0x0000
     */
    pub fn create_acct(ctx: Context<CreateAcct>, owner_id: Vec<u8>, question_nos:String, lamports: u64, trans_fee_lamports:u64) -> Result<()> {
        let user_acct = &mut ctx.accounts.user_acct;
        // msg!("pda :"); 
        // msg!(&acct.key().to_string());
        // msg!("owner_id:");
        // msg!(&owner_id);
        
        if owner_id.len() != 32 {
            // proper error handling omitted for brevity
            msg!("{}",owner_id.len());
            
            panic!("owner_id len error");
        }
        let mut big_brother_owner_id:Vec<u8> = owner_id[..30].to_vec();
        big_brother_owner_id.push(0);
        big_brother_owner_id.push(0);
        
        let (big_brother_acct, _bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[&big_brother_owner_id], ctx.program_id);
        

        user_acct.owner_id = owner_id;
        user_acct.big_brothr_acct_addr = big_brother_acct.to_string();
        if user_acct.big_brothr_acct_addr==user_acct.key().to_string() {
            // myself.
            user_acct.passwd_addr = ctx.accounts.user_passwd_acct.key().to_string();
        } else {
            user_acct.passwd_addr = "".to_string();
        }
        
        user_acct.question_nos = question_nos;
        
        user_acct.bump = ctx.bumps.user_acct;
        
        
        let from_pubkey = user_acct.to_account_info();
        let to_pubkey = ctx.accounts.to_account.to_account_info();

        // https://solanacookbook.com/references/programs.html#how-to-transfer-sol-in-a-program
        // Does the from account have enough lamports to transfer?
        if **from_pubkey.try_borrow_lamports()? < lamports + trans_fee_lamports {
            panic!("InsufficientFundsForTransaction"); 
        }

        if lamports>0 {
            // Debit from_account and credit to_account
            **from_pubkey.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= lamports;
            **to_pubkey.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += lamports;
        }
        
        let to_pubkey2 = ctx.accounts.payer_acct.to_account_info();
        **from_pubkey.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= trans_fee_lamports;
        **to_pubkey2.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += trans_fee_lamports;

        Ok(())
    }

    // handler function (add this next to the create_user_stats function in the game module)
    pub fn change_acct_passwd_addr(ctx: Context<ChangeAcctPasswd>, owner_id: Vec<u8>, question_nos: String, trans_fee_lamports:u64) -> Result<()> {
        if owner_id.len() != 32 {
            // proper error handling omitted for brevity
            panic!("owner_id len error");
        }

        let user_acct = &mut ctx.accounts.user_acct;

        let mut big_brother_owner_id:Vec<u8> = owner_id[..30].to_vec();
        big_brother_owner_id.push(0);
        big_brother_owner_id.push(0);
        
        let (big_brother_acct, _bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[&big_brother_owner_id], ctx.program_id);

        let passwd_addr: String;
        if big_brother_acct.to_string()==user_acct.key().to_string() {
            // myself
            passwd_addr = user_acct.passwd_addr.clone();
        } else {
            panic!("only can change big brother acct");
            // passwd_addr = ctx.accounts.big_brother_acct.passwd_addr.clone();
        }

        if ctx.accounts.user_passwd_acct.is_signer && 
            ctx.accounts.user_passwd_acct.key().to_string()==passwd_addr {
                
        } else {
            msg!("error::::::::");
            msg!("given  passwd:{}, is_signer:{}", ctx.accounts.user_passwd_acct.key(), ctx.accounts.user_passwd_acct.is_signer);
            msg!("user's passwd:{}", user_acct.passwd_addr);
            panic!("passwd addr permit error"); 
        }
        
        // todo : this overwrite is invalid, should fix in future....
        user_acct.passwd_addr = ctx.accounts.new_passwd_acct.key().to_string();
        user_acct.question_nos = question_nos;
        

        let from_pubkey = user_acct.to_account_info();
        let to_pubkey2 = ctx.accounts.payer_acct.to_account_info();

        // let mut account_data = &from_pubkey.try_borrow_mut_data()?[..];
        // let mut acct: AcctEntity = AcctEntity::try_deserialize(&mut account_data)?;
        // msg!("1,{}",acct.passwd_addr);
        // acct.passwd_addr = ctx.accounts.new_passwd_acct.key().to_string();
        // let mut w = vec![];
        // acct.try_serialize(&mut w).unwrap();

        // msg!("2,{}",acct.passwd_addr);
        // // panic!("xxxx");
        // from_pubkey.try_borrow_mut_data() = w.to_ascii_lowercase();


        

        // https://solanacookbook.com/references/programs.html#how-to-transfer-sol-in-a-program
        // Does the from account have enough lamports to transfer?
        if **from_pubkey.try_borrow_lamports()? < trans_fee_lamports {
            panic!("InsufficientFundsForTransaction2"); 
        }        
        **from_pubkey.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= trans_fee_lamports;
        **to_pubkey2.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += trans_fee_lamports;


        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn transfer_acct_lamports(ctx: Context<TransferAcctLamports>, owner_id: Vec<u8>, lamports: u64, trans_fee_lamports:u64) -> Result<()> {
        if owner_id.len() != 32 {
            // proper error handling omitted for brevity
            // msg!("x:{}", lamports);
            panic!("owner_id len error");
        }

        let mut big_brother_owner_id:Vec<u8> = owner_id[..30].to_vec();
        big_brother_owner_id.push(0);
        big_brother_owner_id.push(0);
        
        let (big_brother_acct, _bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[&big_brother_owner_id], ctx.program_id);

        let passwd_addr: String;
        if big_brother_acct.to_string()==ctx.accounts.user_acct.key().to_string() {
            // myself
            passwd_addr = ctx.accounts.user_acct.passwd_addr.clone();
        } else {
            if big_brother_acct.to_string()!=ctx.accounts.big_brother_acct.key().to_string() {
                panic!("given big brother acct error");
            }
            passwd_addr = ctx.accounts.big_brother_acct.passwd_addr.clone();
        }

        if ctx.accounts.user_passwd_acct.is_signer && 
            ctx.accounts.user_passwd_acct.key().to_string()==passwd_addr {

        } else {
            msg!("error::::::::");
            msg!("given  passwd:{}, is_signer:{}", ctx.accounts.user_passwd_acct.key(), ctx.accounts.user_passwd_acct.is_signer);
            msg!("user's passwd:{}", passwd_addr);
            panic!("passwd addr permit ERROR"); 
        }

        let from_pubkey = ctx.accounts.user_acct.to_account_info();
        let to_pubkey = ctx.accounts.to_account.to_account_info();
        // let program_id = ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info();


        // https://solanacookbook.com/references/programs.html#how-to-transfer-sol-in-a-program
        // Does the from account have enough lamports to transfer?
        if **from_pubkey.try_borrow_lamports()? < lamports + trans_fee_lamports {
            panic!("InsufficientFundsForTransaction3"); 
        }
        
        // msg!("0.from:{}",**from_pubkey.try_borrow_mut_lamports()?);

        // Debit from_account and credit to_account
        **from_pubkey.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= lamports;
        **to_pubkey.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += lamports;

        // msg!("1.from:{}",**from_pubkey.try_borrow_mut_lamports()?);

        let to_pubkey2 = ctx.accounts.payer_acct.to_account_info();
 
        **from_pubkey.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= trans_fee_lamports;
        **to_pubkey2.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += trans_fee_lamports;

        // msg!("2.from:{}",**from_pubkey.try_borrow_mut_lamports()?);
        //panic!("test000.");
        Ok(())
    }




}

#[account]
pub struct AcctEntity {
    owner_id: Vec<u8>,
    big_brothr_acct_addr: String,
    passwd_addr: String, // the passwd_addr is valid when big_brothr_acct_addr is the account self, otherwise it's null.
    question_nos: String,
    bump: u8,
}

// validation struct
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(owner_id: Vec<u8>)]
pub struct CreateAcct<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer_acct: Signer<'info>,
    pub user_passwd_acct: Signer<'info>,
    
    // space: 8 discriminator + 4 owner_id length + 32 owner_id + 4 passwd_addr length + 44 passwd_addr + 4 question_nos length + 64 question_nos + 4 big_brothr_acct_addr length + 44 big_brothr_acct_addr + 1 bump
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = payer_acct,
        space = 8 + 4 + 32 + 4 + 44 + 4 + 64 + 4 + 44 + 1, seeds = [&owner_id], bump
    )]
    pub user_acct: Account<'info, AcctEntity>,
    
    /// CHECK: unsafe
    #[account(mut)]
    pub to_account: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

// validation struct
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(owner_id: Vec<u8>)]
pub struct ChangeAcctPasswd<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer_acct: Signer<'info>,
    pub user_passwd_acct: Signer<'info>,
    pub new_passwd_acct: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut, seeds = [&owner_id], bump = user_acct.bump)]
    pub user_acct: Account<'info, AcctEntity>,

    #[account(mut, seeds = [&owner_id[..30],&[0,0]], bump)]
    pub big_brother_acct: Account<'info, AcctEntity>,
}


// validation struct
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(owner_id: Vec<u8>)]
pub struct TransferAcctLamports<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer_acct: Signer<'info>,
    pub user_passwd_acct: Signer<'info>,
    
    #[account(mut, seeds = [&owner_id], bump )]
    pub user_acct: Account<'info, AcctEntity>,

    /// CHECK: unsafe
    #[account(mut)]
    pub to_account: AccountInfo<'info>,

    #[account(mut, seeds = [&owner_id[..30],&[0,0]], bump)]
    pub big_brother_acct: Account<'info, AcctEntity>,
    
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

// solana program extend BA3YWB1TPRqMcKjMRBugDqjcowNiZJb4FcPwjWfg9aCD 20000

=====
essyaccess.ts:
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program, BN } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Easyaccess } from "../target/types/easyaccess";

import { bytesToHex, hexToBytes } from "viem";

import nacl from "tweetnacl";

import {
    PublicKey, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, SystemProgram,
    Transaction,
    sendAndConfirmTransaction,
} from '@solana/web3.js';

import web3 from "@solana/web3.js";

import { expect } from 'chai';

const connection = new web3.Connection(
    "http://127.0.0.1:8899", // web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"), 
    "confirmed");



const privk0 = new Uint8Array([
    147, 240, 231, 155, 4, 5, 11, 134, 204, 12, 221,
    145, 54, 157, 77, 75, 228, 6, 26, 136, 248, 6,
    81, 218, 50, 66, 117, 113, 122, 234, 95, 96, 11,
    99, 95, 213, 231, 32, 50, 238, 68, 31, 84, 150,
    13, 227, 171, 71, 192, 103, 37, 13, 112, 196, 65,
    222, 43, 221, 177, 242, 112, 101, 141, 196
]);

const privk1 = new Uint8Array([
    56, 77, 23, 179, 55, 136, 218, 145, 201, 243, 98,
    12, 80, 160, 33, 217, 170, 195, 118, 182, 160, 98,
    246, 249, 238, 13, 38, 88, 189, 53, 38, 21, 137,
    201, 28, 252, 246, 36, 193, 151, 5, 155, 173, 205,
    19, 219, 145, 24, 155, 143, 87, 189, 76, 216, 68,
    133, 138, 19, 47, 222, 91, 147, 62, 43
]);

const passwdAcct0 = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(privk0);
const passwdAcct1 = web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(privk1);
console.log("passwdAcct0:", passwdAcct0.publicKey.toBase58());
console.log("passwdAcct1:", passwdAcct1.publicKey.toBase58());

const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env()
anchor.setProvider(provider)

const payer = provider.wallet;
console.log("payer:", payer.publicKey.toBase58());

const ownerId0 = hexToBytes(
    "0x477a3efac4b9f407e6abbef158c7312585d675f688e11949c468b8d4dc560000");
const ownerId1 = hexToBytes(
    "0x477a3efac4b9f407e6abbef158c7312585d675f688e11949c468b8d4dc560001");


async function airdropTransfer(toPubkey: PublicKey, amountInSol: number) {


    let balance1 = await connection.getBalance(toPubkey);
    console.log(`${toPubkey} balance before airdrop: ${balance1}`);


    let payerXXX = web3.Keypair.generate();
    // console.log("pubkey:", payer.publicKey.toBase58());
    // // 3UuZygtJF5w61m2ApmVsAAMzbtipZDbPp83S9keKteuU

    let airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
        payerXXX.publicKey,
        (1 + amountInSol) * web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
    );
    await connection.confirmTransaction({ signature: airdropSignature });

    // Create a transfer instruction for transferring SOL from wallet_1 to wallet_2
    const transferInstruction = SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: payerXXX.publicKey,
        toPubkey: toPubkey,
        lamports: amountInSol * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, // Convert transferAmount to lamports
    });

    // Add the transfer instruction to a new transaction
    const transaction = new Transaction().add(transferInstruction);

    // Send and confirm transaction
    // Note: feePayer is by default the first signer, or payer, if the parameter is not set
    await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [payerXXX]);

    let balance2 = await connection.getBalance(toPubkey);
    console.log(`${toPubkey} balance after airdrop: ${balance2}`);
}

describe("easyaccess", () => {

    // console.log("passwdAddr:xxxxxxx223:",anchor.workspace.Easyaccess );
    const program = anchor.workspace.Easyaccess as Program<Easyaccess>

    const [acctPDA0, _acctBump] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
        [
            ownerId0,
            // anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode(ownerId),
            // payer.publicKey.toBuffer(),
        ],
        program.programId
    )
    const [acctPDA1, _acctBump2] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
        [
            ownerId1,
            // anchor.utils.bytes.utf8.encode(ownerId),
            // payer.publicKey.toBuffer(),
        ],
        program.programId
    )

    console.log("acctPDA0 in client:", acctPDA0.toBase58());
    console.log("acctPDA1 in client:", acctPDA1.toBase58());

    it('Sets and changes passwd addr!', async () => {
        console.log("passwdAddr:xxxxxxx224a");

        // create account 0
        await airdropTransfer(acctPDA0, 3);
        const questionNos = "U2FsdGVkX1/9hml4Tf3VLEBNhUoJ5vzRZkX4UfEE2bE=";
        //  AompEk8ZGRwTmUwR41kRkSPJddsZeSsXMuGUJeRSixXt
        await program.methods.createAcct(
            Buffer.from(ownerId0), questionNos,
            new BN(1 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL), new BN(10))
            .accounts({
                payerAcct: payer.publicKey,
                userPasswdAcct: passwdAcct0.publicKey,
                userAcct: acctPDA0,
                toAccount: payer.publicKey,
            }).signers([passwdAcct0])
            .rpc()

        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100));
        console.log("passwdAddr:xxxxxxx224b,acctPDA0 in client:", acctPDA0.toBase58());
        let v1 = (await program.account.acctEntity.fetch(acctPDA0)).ownerId;
        let v2 = (await program.account.acctEntity.fetch(acctPDA0)).bigBrothrAcctAddr;
        let v3 = (await program.account.acctEntity.fetch(acctPDA0)).passwdAddr;
        let v4 = (await program.account.acctEntity.fetch(acctPDA0)).questionNos;
        let v5 = (await program.account.acctEntity.fetch(acctPDA0)).bump;
        console.log("0-ownerId:", v1);
        console.log("0-ownerId2:", bytesToHex(v1));
        console.log("0-bigBrothrAcctAddr:", v2);
        console.log("0-passwdAddr:", v3);
        console.log("0-questionNos:", v4);
        console.log("0-bump:", v5);


        // transfer from account 0 to account 1;
        let balance0 = await connection.getBalance(acctPDA0);
        let balance1 = await connection.getBalance(acctPDA1);
        console.log("balance,before transfer,0 & 1:", balance0, ",", balance1, payer.publicKey.toBase58());
        await program.methods.transferAcctLamports(
            Buffer.from(ownerId0),
            new BN(1 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL), new BN(10))
            .accounts({
                payerAcct: payer.publicKey,
                userPasswdAcct: passwdAcct0.publicKey,
                userAcct: acctPDA0,
                toAccount: acctPDA1,
                bigBrotherAcct: acctPDA0,
            }).signers([passwdAcct0])
            .rpc();

        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 100));

        balance0 = await connection.getBalance(acctPDA0);
        balance1 = await connection.getBalance(acctPDA1);
        console.log("balance,after- transfer,0 & 1:", balance0, ",", balance1);

        // create account 1
        await program.methods.createAcct(
            Buffer.from(ownerId1), questionNos,
            new BN(0 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL), new BN(10))
            .accounts({
                payerAcct: payer.publicKey,
                userPasswdAcct: passwdAcct0,
                userAcct: acctPDA1,
                toAccount: acctPDA1,
            })
            .rpc()
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 800));
        console.log("passwdAddr:xxxxxxx224b,acctPDA in client3333:", acctPDA1);
        v1 = (await program.account.acctEntity.fetch(acctPDA1)).ownerId;
        v2 = (await program.account.acctEntity.fetch(acctPDA1)).bigBrothrAcctAddr;
        v3 = (await program.account.acctEntity.fetch(acctPDA1)).passwdAddr;
        v4 = (await program.account.acctEntity.fetch(acctPDA1)).questionNos;
        v5 = (await program.account.acctEntity.fetch(acctPDA1)).bump;
        console.log("1-ownerId:", v1);
        console.log("1-ownerId2:", bytesToHex(v1));
        console.log("1-bigBrothrAcctAddr:", v2);
        console.log("1-passwdAddr:", v3);
        console.log("1-questionNos:", v4);
        console.log("1-bump:", v5);


        ////


        // transfer from account 1 to account 0;
        balance0 = await connection.getBalance(acctPDA0);
        balance1 = await connection.getBalance(acctPDA1);
        console.log("222,balance,before transfer,0 & 1:", balance0, ",", balance1, payer.publicKey.toBase58());
        await program.methods.transferAcctLamports(
            Buffer.from(ownerId1),
            new BN(0.1 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL), new BN(10))
            .accounts({
                payerAcct: payer.publicKey,
                userPasswdAcct: passwdAcct0.publicKey,
                userAcct: acctPDA1,
                toAccount: acctPDA0,
                bigBrotherAcct: acctPDA0,
            }).signers([passwdAcct0])
            .rpc();

        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 800));

        balance0 = await connection.getBalance(acctPDA0);
        balance1 = await connection.getBalance(acctPDA1);
        console.log("222,balance,after- transfer,0 & 1:", balance0, ",", balance1);



        let questionNos2 = "++++GVkX1/9hml4Tf3VLEBNhUoJ5vzRZkX4UfEE2bE=";
        // change password.
        let passwd = (await program.account.acctEntity.fetch(acctPDA0)).passwdAddr;
        let qs = (await program.account.acctEntity.fetch(acctPDA0)).questionNos;
        console.log("passwd,before change:", passwd);
        console.log("passwd,before change2:", qs);
        await program.methods.changeAcctPasswdAddr(
            Buffer.from(ownerId0),
            questionNos2, new BN(10))
            .accounts({
                payerAcct: payer.publicKey,
                userPasswdAcct: passwdAcct0.publicKey,
                newPasswdAcct: passwdAcct1.publicKey,
                userAcct: acctPDA0,
                bigBrotherAcct: acctPDA0,
            }).signers([passwdAcct0, passwdAcct1])
            .rpc();

        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 800));
        balance0 = await connection.getBalance(acctPDA0);
        passwd = (await program.account.acctEntity.fetch(acctPDA0)).passwdAddr;
        qs = (await program.account.acctEntity.fetch(acctPDA0)).questionNos;
        console.log("passwd,after  change:", passwd);  // here is line 250
        console.log("passwd,after change2:", qs, balance0);

        return;

    })

});




Oh my god, it's finally done! The bug was caused by: In my lib.rs code, the struct ChangeAcctPasswd, the field big_brother_acct is mut, but I actually don't need to modify it, so I removed the mut. After removing mut, the modification to user_acct took effect. I guess it might be because the two values of user_acct and big_brother_acct are exactly the same. Additionally, I also removed the mut on big_brother_acct in TransferAcctLamports.
==============
My inspiration comes from :
The values inside the PDA is not being updated
